# Как можно назначить тексту класс?

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы стилизовать эти надписи в опросе: "**Нравится - 1 (100%)**", "**Так себе - 0 (0%)**" и т.д., но им не назначен никакой класс. Можно ли назначить каждой этой надписи через js один класс для оформления?

Исходный код опроса выглядит так:

```html
<div class="vote_list"><div id="dle-poll-list-118">Нравится - 1 (100%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll1" style="width:100%;">100%</span></div>Так себе - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll2" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div>Не очень - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll3" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div>Мне понравился - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll4" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div>Узнать результаты - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll5" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно назначить стили для общего контейнера (контейнеров), и затем перебить стилем для тех элементов которые мы можем указать в правиле. Получится тоже самое, как если бы у текста был класс. А вообще, что мешает изменить верстку?

```css
.vote_list {
  color: red; /* цвет "текста" */
}

.pollprogress > span {
  color: blue; /* цвет "остального текста" */
}
```

```html
<div class="vote_list"><div id="dle-poll-list-118">Нравится - 1 (100%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll1" style="width:100%;">100%</span></div>Так себе - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll2" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div>Не очень - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll3" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div>Мне понравился - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll4" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div>Узнать результаты - 0 (0%)<br>
<div class="pollprogress"><span class="poll5" style="width:0%;">0%</span></div></div></div>
```